# Display final score from windows 8 game c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, comparison

I created a game in c# for windows 8 and everything works like it is supposed to but after the user plays the game the score is displayed in a text box and it is supposed to also display on the following screen displaying the score and text and thumbs up images depending on how high it is.

The problem is the score isn't being carried over. The code I use gets the constructor from the game page then the score, the code is below:

```
Var arcade = new arcadeMode();
ScoreNum.text = arcade.score.toString();


//then sample code to display images based on score
if(arcade.score < 100)
   {
      Usermessage.text = "try again.";
      Thumbdown.visibility = visibility.visible;
   }
```

I think my problem is actually getting the saved score from the game because it must only be getting the textbox value from before the game started. Not really sure how to save the score without a database though. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: do not bind your logic to UI values. Make it dependent on abstract data model. Just an advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ArcadeMode` is essentially your data model, but *gets the constructor from the game page* doesn't really have meaning.  Assuming you have an instance of `ArcadeMode` on your game page and it includes the actual score, with the code above, you've just created a brand new second instance of that same class with the score initialized to 0.

One quick way, since it appears it's just a simple piece of data you want to pass, is use the second parameter of [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh702394.aspx). Wherever it is you navigate to the thumbs-up page, add the current value of your 'score' variable as the second parameter, for example:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(ThumbsUpPage), score)
```

Then in the [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx) event of *ThumbsUpPage* you can access the value you passed via the [Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs.parameter.aspx) property of the argument, for example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
   String score = e.Parameter;
   ...
```

Another option is to give the `ArcadeMode` class instance a larger scope (i.e., not make it a variable on the main page). You could make it a member of the App class, for instance, and then it would be available for all the pages in your app.